# Override VoiceOver message in UITextField - iOS Accessibilty

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have a UITextField that contains "£24 pm" but I want voiceover to say "£24 per month". By setting:

```
[textView setAccessibilityLabel:@"£24 per month"];
```

VoiceOver reads out "£24 per month £24 pm".

How do I stop the message in the UITextField from being read out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the accessibility label to describe the text field (as if it was a key) and the accessibility value for its value.

```
textField.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString(@"Price", nil);
// textField.accessibilityValue = @"£24 per month";
textField.accessibilityValue = [self transformedPrice:textField.text];
```

`-transformedPrice:` should do whatever operation to transform the actual text in your textField to what should be used in voice over. (Don't forget localization)

Comment: But it does not matter. Text is still being pronounced instead of accessibilityValue or label.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `accessibilityValue` to `nil` or a blank string and the `accessibilityLabel` to `@"£24 per month"`.